# Doctrine preUpdate Listener not setting field values in database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this code

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
    $args->isActive = false;

    $meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
    $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $entity);
}
```

I tried many times but its not updating the field.

Answer (score 2):

Should be `$entity->isActive = false;`
 instead of  `$args->isActive = false;`.